# IP зарубежного сервера определяется как российский

Tags: ip, хостинг, vps, геолокация, vds

Дано:

1. известный российский хостер (не буду указывать название компании, дабы не посчитали рекламой/антирекламой) с дата-центрами в России и в Нидерландах
2. стандартная услуга по аренде VPS/VDS сервера в дата-центре в Нидерландах с минимальными характеристиками и ценой по низу рынка
3. настроенный на данном "голландском" сервере VPN через Outline (Shadowsocks)

Что имеем:
Обход блокировок на таком "своем" VPN работает вполне сносно, НО !!! половина сервисов по идентификации ip адресов определяют мой голландский ip как российский и почему-то указывают в поле геолокация Москва. Многие зарубежные сайты (сервисы, службы, соцсети, магазины и т.д.) при заходе к ним с таким "голландским" ip автоматом переключаются на русский язык или открываются с поддоменных имен "ru" (по типу https://ru.wikipedia.org или https://www.paypal.com/ru/). Т.е. другими словами, не смотря на VPN c зарубежными ip сайты продолжают видеть меня как пользователя из РФ.

В саппорте хостинг-провайдера объясняют подобное какими-то устаревшими гео-айпи базами и невозможностью самого провайдера каким-либо образом повлиять на эту проблему. Ну типа дата-центр мы вам дали реально зарубежный, а то что кто-то видит ваш ip как российский  - не наши проблемы....

Собственно сам вопрос:

1. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным подскажите есть ли смысл менять одного российского провайдера на другого? или такие проблемы у всех российских провайдеров и лучше заказывать подобные услуги у зарубежных?
2. Из-за чего происходит такое гео-несоответствие? Имеет ли оно какую-то техническую природу? или это какие-то юридические особенности принадлежности ip адресов к хостерам, зарегистрированным в России?

Comment: Если сервер находится в Нидерландах, то почему ему не быть сервером с Нидерландов? Даже если это хостер с рф

Comment: Можно попробовать вручную поскачивать старые и новые версии какого-нибудь [geolite](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite2-free-geolocation-data?lang=en) например и посмотреть, какую страну они определяют для вашего ip-адреса

Comment: Та же самая проблема! Думаю в сторону DNS утечки, но не уверен, что проблема на моей стороне, а не их голландского сервера. Удалось решить?

Answer (score 0):

1. Сам пользуюсь данным провайдером, такой фигни не замечал. Возможно, присутствует элемент рандома. Также на `2ip` можно видеть, что имя компьютера выглядит как `hosted-by-***.ru` . Не исключено, что некоторые сайты смотрят именно на этот параметр. Также мой Нидерландский ip палится как принадлежащий хостинг провайдеру, и я с таким явно не один. Был до этого у другого провайдера, так там ещё хуже, ip не просто ошибочно определялись как российские, так ещё и были зарегистрированы в РФ. Тут хоть регистрации иностранная.
2. Если же сайты не интересуют такие мелочи, как имя хоста, то есть ещё метки, на которые они смотрят. Это язык системы, время и тп. Для изменения этих вещей есть свои методы. У некоторых коммерческих ВПН это встроено в программу, как у windscribe, у которых все это находится опять-таки в расширении. А самостоятельно можно использовать расширения, которые выполняют те же самые функции, например `Vytal`.